# Modify css Variable in media query using Tailwind

Tags: html, css, media-queries, tailwind-css

Is it possible to modify a css variable in a media query using tailwind?

Like this maybe: `md:[--variable:2]`

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind...It is possible just like that :)